Itô's formula Application
Let $(W_t)_{t \in [0,T]}$ a Wiener process/Brownian motion, $b,B: \Bbb R^m \times [0,T] \to \Bbb R$ two continous functions, $Y$ a $\Bbb R$-valued random variable and
$$ dZ_t= b(Z_t,t)dt+B(Z_t,t)dW, \ \ \ \ Z_0=Y   $$
a stochastic dgl.
Question: Can to this sdgl the Itô's formula ("stochastic chain rule) be applied?
Recall Itô's formula is usually stated as follows: Let
$$dX_t=a(t)dt+ A(t)dW $$
a sdgl with $(a(t))_{t \in [0,T]},(A(t))_{t \in [0,T]}$ two stochastic processes such that $a(t)$ is $L^1$, $A(t)$is $L^2$ (in order to assure that Ito integrals exist; eg thats the case when $a,A$ have a.s. continuous paths),
$h \in C^{2,1}(\Bbb R \times [0,T], \Bbb R)$ twice differentible in 1st variable, 1 in second, then for $U_t:= h(X_t, t)$ we get stochastic differential
$$ dU_t=\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}dX +\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial t^2}A(t)^2dt  $$
The crucial question is that in "clasical" formulation $a(t), A(t)$ are stochastic processes, $b$ and $B$ from above accept also random variables as "left" arguments. On the other hand can't we simply reformulate $b$ and $B$ as usual stochastic processes by setting simply
$$  \overline{b}(s):= b(Z(s),s), \ \ \ \overline{B}(s):= B(Z(s),s)  $$
And then simply we can apply Itô's formula to
$$ dZ_s= \overline{b}(s)ds +\overline{B}(s)dW    $$
? Aren't we here "in business" again? But somehow this appears fishy to me. Could somebody clarify what's wrong here with such naive application of Itô's formula by recasting more or less $b(Z_t,t), B(Z_t,t) $ to $ \overline{b}(s), \overline{B}(s)$ in this setting?

It is well known that Ito's formula exists for $h(X_t,t)$ where $X$ is a semi martingale and $h$ a sufficiently differentiable function. You seem to be of the wrong opinion that it matters how exactly an "SDE" for $X$ looks like. This is almost wrong. All we need to know is the semi martingale decomposition $X_t=M_t+A_t$ and the quadratic variation of the local martingale $M,.$

The first SDE in your post has notational problems that leads to a lot of confusion. When $b$ and $B$ are functions on $\mathbb R^m\times[0,T]$ the only reasonable interpretation is
$$
dZ_{\color{red}t}= b(Z_{\color{red}t},t)dt+B(Z_{\color{red}t},t),dW,
$$ which should answer a question further down in your post.

@KurtG.: Have tried to clear up notational problems, but the question stays the same: Is Ito's formula appliable to the corrected sdgl as you wrote in your last comment? If not, why?

@KurtG.: The crux is which "coefficients" $b,B$ my sdgl is allowd to have in order to that Ito's formula becomes allowable. Only in $t$, or also "coupled" with $Z_t$, so of type $b(Z_t,t)$ (analogously with B)? That's my question

You are still confused. Ito's formula is applicable to a smooth enough $h$ and a semi martingale $X,.$ Period. It looks like you are confusing the equation for your $X$ with existence theorems for solutions of SDEs. That would be then a totally different question.

@KurtG.: firstly, I'm not focussed on subtilities about $h$, so let h take "as smooth as neccessary". Then, do I understand you correctly, that then applicability of Ito fmla to such $h$ and $(Z_t)_t$ (which is given as a solution of the sdgl you wrote in 2nd comment) depends only on if such $(Z_t)_t$ is semi martingal,right? Then the follow up question would be not precisely about existence, but under which conditions on $b,B$ (ie dependence on $t$ only vs also coupling with $Z_t$ allowed) the solution $Z_t$ is a semi martingal. That's the better question focussing my initial problem, right?

Yes. We are getting closer to a reasonable question. In this generality the answer is however not much more concrete. As soon as you are able to say that $Z$ "solves" $dZ_{\color{red}t}= b(Z_{\color{red}t},t)dt+B(Z_{\color{red}t},t),dW$ we know that $Z$ is a semi martingale. This is because the SDE is nothing else than an integral equation:$$Z_t= Z_0+\int_0^tb(Z_s,s),ds+\int_0^tB(Z_s,s),dW_s,.$$ As soon as you can say that these integrals exist that $Z$ is inevitably a semi martingale. More concrete answers you get from the existence theorems for such SDEs.
